# Python update value for key 'x' when a key pair ("y":"z") exists

Tags: python

Python update value for key 'x' when a key pair ("y":"z") exists.

Update 'Online' to False only for Subjects 'Mathematics' and 'French'

## data =

```
     [{"subject": "Science",
      "Online" : True,
      "Professor" "John"},
      
      {"subject": "Mathematics",
      "Online" : True,
      "Professor" "John"},
      
      {"subject": "French",
      "Online" : True,
      "Professor" "John"},
      
      {"subject": "English",
      "Online" : True,
      "Professor" "John"}]
```

## updated_data =

```
     [{"subject": "Science",
      "Online" : True,
      "Professor" "John"},
      
      {"subject": "Mathematics",
      "Online" : False,
      "Professor" "John"},
      
      {"subject": "French",
      "Online" : False,
      "Professor" "John"},
      
      {"subject": "English",
      "Online" : True,
      "Professor" "John"}]
```

My actual data has around 150 such records and at least to 40 + records this Online value should be updated to False for selected subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
for e in data:
    if e["subject"] in {"Mathematics", "French"}:
        e["Online"] = False
```

Comment: A good practice is to use set when looking for a value in a collection.

Comment: For only a few different values, using a tuple is more efficient than using a set.

Comment: @kaya3 Could be... Unless the set is defined outside of `for` loop.

Comment: @VisioN - Though I agree for the general case (search in O(1) vs O(n)) I think for a collection of size 2 it won't really make a difference

Comment: @GiladGreen Well, it depends on the number of iterations you need to do for `data`, which goes down to O(n) vs O(2n). In this particular example it won't be a problem, but it's probably helpful to demonstrate, how to make it properly? Just my thoughts...

Comment: @kaya3 Already for this case of size 2, tuple [looks slower](https://repl.it/repls/YoungEmbellishedCircles#main.py).